# How can I reduce the CPU usage of my application?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qthread

My application involves taking backup of certain sqlite database as set by user. This backup is based on certain conditions. So in order to do that I am using a worker object(running on QThread) do check if the conditions match. If the condition matches I take the backup. My problem is, i have checked the task manager and my application always uses a minimum of 25%(since the thread is running). If i disable the automatic backup, it is back to normal. Am I doing anything wrong or is this normal ? Please can anyone point me how to keep the cpu usage low? Below is my code for the automatic backup thread.

```
void Automatic_Backup_Logic::Thread_Run()
{
    QSettings settings(ORGANISATION, APPLICATION_NAME);
    while(!m_Stop){
        // First check the backup type
        int backup_type = settings.value(BACKUP_TYPE).toInt();
        QTime BackupTime = qvariant_cast<QTime>(settings.value(BACKUP_TIME));

        // Check for backup time; if it's in range only then do backup
        if(!Check_Backup_Time(BackupTime)){
            continue;
        }

        switch (backup_type)
        {
            case BACKUP_TYPE_MANUAL:
            // do nothing here
                continue;

            case BACKUP_TYPE_DAILY:
                Backup_Daily();
                break;

            case BACKUP_TYPE_WEEKLY:
                Backup_Weekly();
                break;

            case BACKUP_TYPE_MONTHLY:
                Backup_Monthly();
                break;

            case BACKUP_TYPE_YEARLY:
                Backup_Yearly();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        // Wait for the current backup minute to pass by to avoid multiple copies
        QTime t1 = qvariant_cast<QTime> (settings.value(BACKUP_TIME));
        while(t1.minute()==QTime::currentTime().minute()){
            if(m_Stop)
                return;
            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I am running this thread by standard Qt Procedure that is creating a worker thread and using moveToThread() function

Comment: Unless there is a `sleep()` or something similar in `Check_Backup_Time()`, you have a busy-loop there. I assume you have 4 cores on your system, and your application uses 1 core 100 %. So, you need to a sleep() (or usleep() or nanosleep() or poll()) call somewhere when there's nothing to do.

Comment: @Rene Since I am dependent on system time, I may not be able to use sleep(). Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What do you mean by dependent on system time? What is preventing you from using something like `std::this_thread::sleep_for(...)`? Even setting it to some rather short value like 0.1s or even 0.01s should help if you can't predict approximately when the next backup will happen and need it to happen *quickly*.

Comment: suggest you research ` QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents` flag. It instructs the processEvents method of QEventLoop to go into a wait state if there are no events to process. You would then exit the processEvents loop by posting a quit event rather than setting a flag.

Comment: @Qubit Thanks for pointing out, Initially I though of waiting till the next backup time, but the problem was if user may have changed the time, the backup would be missed, now i put 5 secs sleep now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, I put delay in my thread now everything is working as expected. Thank you all

Edited Code

```
    // Check for backup time; if it's in range only then do backup
    while(!Check_Backup_Time(BackupTime) && !m_Stop){
        QThread::sleep(1);
        BackupTime = qvariant_cast<QTime>(settings.value(BACKUP_TIME));
    }
```

Comment: Just in case you are "afraid" of starting the backup 5 seconds too late in the worst case: You can use much shorter sleep times and still your application will not use a lot more of CPU time. I think that even with a 10-milliseconds-sleep it would not use more than 1-2 % CPU time.

Answer (score 2):

A clean approach to this problem would be to make use of Qt's signal/slot mechanism.

Just setup a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) with the remaining time to backup and connect its [`timeout()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout) signal with a backup slot, like:

```
class Automatic_Backup_Logic {
public:
    Automatic_Backup_Logic() {
        connect(&mBackupTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Automatic_Backup_Logic::performBackup);
    }

    void scheduleBackup(QTime backupTime) {
        int millisRemaining = getTimeRemaining(backupTime);
        mBackupTimer.singleShot(millisRemaining);
    }

private slots:
    void performBackup() {
    }

private:
    QTimer mBackupTimer;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this code is 1) I need to have another logic that keeps calling the scheduleBackup if the app is going to run continuously, which is my case, or else not use single shot. 2) Another logic for getTimeRemaining has to be written. 3) If the user changes the backup time, after the backup is scheduled, a backup would be missed, so again I have to take care of that stuff by calling scheduleBackup. Instead of that I think checking the backup time every 1 second is good enough. Correct me if i am wrong